# Apache Kafka, node js and Point-to-point workflow

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

So I am just starting to explore kafka (with node js) and I am using kafka-node module to interact with kafka.

how to id implement point-to-point workflow? i.e. One or more consumers can consume the messages in the queue, **but a particular message can be consumed by a maximum of one consumer only**. Once a consumer reads a message in the queue, it should disappear from that queue.

I just wrote some test consumer code (see below). When i run multiple instances of this consumer code, and push new messages to a topic, all the instances of consumers pull the message (and display on console). I want only 1 of the consumers to pull the message and process it.

```
var kafka = require("kafka-node");
var client = new kafka.Client();
var Consumer = kafka.Consumer;

var consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [
            { topic: 'testtopic**strong text**', partition: 0 }
        ],
        {
            autoCommit: true,
        }
    )

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a common consumer group in your consumers in order to get mutually exclusive distribution of messages.

You also need to have at least as many partitions in your topic as consumers on your consumer group since each consumer in the group gets a different partition